# SSRS Render params into a URL

Tags: ssrs

We have a private SSRS database and have created a public atom url to import the data into Google Sheet. It works, but returns each row as a string. It doesn't return in table format.No columns.

URL is in format below:

=importfeed("SERVER:/FOLDERLOCATION/%252fJK%252fFOLDER%252fFILENAME&rc:ItemPath=Tablix1/atom?token=!xyz"

And return as "A B C D" instead of "A" "B" "C" "D".

What do we need to add in URL so data is returned in a table format?

Comment: Have you tried using EXCEL or CSV format? `&rs:Format=EXCEL`  Have a look at [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-parameter-reference?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yes I have tried that but looks ‘atom.xml’ file is missing style sheet hence importfeed and importxml is returning data in raw format.